# How to track JS generated ciphertext in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: javascript, html, console, analysis

I am using TP-Link wifi router to set open VPN. However there's a stupid restriction that it only allows port 1024 to 65535. I am trying to override the router's configuration but not familiar with HTML and JS action process, so I need some help.

I found that when I set the port, the website post a request to this URL:
https://tplinkwifi.net/cgi-bin/luci/;stok=XXXX91f39b5b0d08d44177249d26XXXX/admin/openvpn?form=config
, with payload:

**sign:** XXXX533e31a404dcbb1b8d27c1e72f5b69bb052eddfc6f6d9a6376ca7c925867a03271a8943b5ab976014bfbae8cedde88b8c1286c7b8e1d9e4ec9cda1c0XXXX

**data:** XXXXrCx4fBmktIRjayY3oy9yNPbR+pZXTi1mt6hKn21Dy0pBpVaFoJ2mSEorp8A4c+x1eFEAe0GCZpKp4i9qqEWI/orsua9v90L+e963dqN/WnZyA6k288lphEM6SsB6jFHBIyOCNKjgU1WCPQMWdjn3F6WFiKdHeGLZMrBqy6xgtAy+Qw+aAn54tLDNXXXX

Before the request sent, there's no other request. Can I realize like that, the values of sign and data are created locally by Javascript? If so, it is about the setting including the port number. If I can analyze how these values are created, I can bypass the restriction and try to make a port 443 configuration and send the request.

I try to read the Javascript behind but it is too complex. Is it possible to track how this encrypted value generated? Thanks!

I try to decode these base64 like value but cannot see the plain text. The HTML structure are complex and wrapped deeply, I don't know how to tract the action process or how this value comes out.

Comment: There is a reason for the restriction: RFC1700 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1700. Surely, this doesn't answer your question, but it's for a reason your router won't let you by default.

Comment: Maybe there are some reasons but I heard another brand ASUS's router does support OpenVPN on port 443. It seems TP-link has insisted the restriction for years regardless of many users' opinions to ask for open.

Answer (score 0):

Hard work for the whole evening, I tried something:

After analyzing the JavaScript code, I found the encryption function is wrapped in jQuery. Use jQuery object to apply the function and encode the plaintext got from JavaScript analysis in Chrome devtools:

```
url = "https://192.168.0.1/cgi-bin/luci/;stok=XXXX6ff74d538ab3be198260400fXXXX/admin/openvpn?form=config";

x = jQuery.su.encryptor.dataEncrypt("operation=write&enabled=on&wan=&proto=tcp&port=443&serverip=10.10.0.0&mask=255.255.255.0&connection=10&access=internet&cert_exist=true");

body = new URLSearchParams(x).toString();

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"};

fetch(url, {method:"POST", headers:headers, body:body}).then(x=>x.text()).then(x=>console.log(x));
```

The above script can use the plaintext as command to set VPN configuration. Unfortunately, it did not pass backend validation. When I passed port in range 1024~65535, it succeeded. But when it comes to port 443, it did no change at all.

I think I've answered my own question. However I still cannot override the TP-link Wi-Fi router's VPN configuration.